# Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::stream_publish()

Tags: php

Well I am trying to post on facebook's wall but I get this error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::stream_publish()`

The code I am trying is this

```
<?php

define('FB_APIKEY', '<Your Api Key>');
define('FB_SECRET', '<Secret>');
define('FB_SESSION', '<Session>');

require_once('facebook.php');

echo "post on wall";
echo "<br/>";

try {
 $facebook = new Facebook(FB_APIKEY, FB_SECRET);
 $facebook->api_client->session_key = FB_SESSION;
 $facebook->api_client->expires = 0;
 $message = '';

 $attachment = array(
 'name' => $_POST["name"],
 'href' => $_POST["href"],
 'description' => $_POST["description"],
 'media' => array(array('type' => 'image',
 'src' => $_POST["src"],
 'href' => $_POST["href"])));

 $action_links = array( array('text' => 'Visit Us', 'href' => '<link to some place here>'));

 $attachment = json_encode($attachment);
 $action_links = json_encode($action_links);

 $target_id = "<Target Id>";
 $session_key = FB_SESSION;

 if( $facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message, $attachment, $action_links, null, $target_id)) {
 echo "Added on FB Wall";
 }
} catch(Exception $e) {
 echo $e . "<br />";
 }
?>
```

Comment: What library you are using? Where is the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it is written in the error message there is no method "stream_publish" in $facebook->api_client.
Consult the manual of the library you are using to connect to the facebook.

Answer (score 0):

If `$facebook->api_client` is not an object, then the line:

```
 $facebook->api_client->session_key = FB_SESSION;
```

Will make php silently cast `$facebook->api_client` to an object of type `stdClass`. Which, later on down the code, will cause the `Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::stream_publish()` that you are getting.

Try changing:
     ...

```
 $facebook = new Facebook(FB_APIKEY, FB_SECRET);
 $facebook->api_client->session_key = FB_SESSION;
 $facebook->api_client->expires = 0;

 ...
```

to catch for when api_client is false (or, perhaps, not an object):

```
 ...

 $facebook = new Facebook(FB_APIKEY, FB_SECRET);

 if (!( $facebook->api_client )) {
   //throw error 
   echo 'Need to sort this bit out';
   exit;
 }   

 $facebook->api_client->session_key = FB_SESSION;
 $facebook->api_client->expires = 0;

 ...
```

And then, if that does throw an error, you'd need to investigate why `$facebook->api_client` is null.